# jQuery AJAX check if email exists in database not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery, AJAX, PHP, and MySQL to check if an email entered into a form already exists in a database.
This is my current jQuery code :

```
$.post('check-email.php', {'suEmail' : $suEmail}, function(data) {
  if(data=='exists') {
    validForm = false;
    $suRememberMeCheckbox.css('top', '70px');
    $suRememberMeText.css('top', '68px');
    $signUpSubmit.css('top', '102px');
    $tosppText.css('top', '115px');
    $suBox.css('height', '405px');
    $suBox.css('top', '36%');
    $errorText.text('The email has been taken.');
    return false;
  };
});
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<?php include("dbconnect.php") ?>
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '" .$_POST['suEmail'] . "'";
    $select = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($select) > 0) {
      echo "exists";
    }
?>
```

When I go through with the sign up form, when I use an email already in the database, the error text never changes to what I specified, but instead to some other error cases I have coded. Why is this not working! Thanks so much!

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: What error does it shows?

Comment: Put alert or console.log and check "data" value

Comment: Okay, I just added a console.log for the data value. When I change the echo to something other than 'exists', like 'exist', it logs 'exist' to the console. However, when I keep the echo as 'exists', nothing logs to the console. Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you change `exists` in the jquery code when you changed the `exists` to `exist` in the php? Is it really neccessary to use semicolon after the `};` in the jquery `if statement`?

Comment: No. I guess the jQuery function is getting the data, however, the form still goes through to the success page instead of displaying an error. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may have extra whitespace in response

Try:

```
if(data.trim()=='exists') {
```

Comment: I just added that, however, the form still goes through to the success page instead of displaying an error. Thanks so much!

Comment: note you can't use `return false;` in that callback to prevent a form submit if that's what you are doing. Ajax is asynchronous